# Openshift: Why I don't see application logs in Kibana?

Tags: logging, openshift

I've installed cluster logging for Openshift. I can check that application logs are collected via elasticsearch_im_app_XXXXXXXX jobs but I can't see them in Kibana. I have cluster admin role and can see infra and audit logs.
The job has the following output:

```
    No indices to delete
    Current write index for app-write: app-000003
    Checking results from _rollover call
    Next write index for app-write: app-000004
    Checking if app-000004 exists
    Checking if app-000004 is the write index for app-write
    Done!
```

Any advices?

Comment: are you using the correct index in kibana?

Comment: @SpringLearner could you please clarify what do you mean by correct index? I use default indexes: App*, Infra*, Audit*

Comment: while you push the logs, you must be sending the logs to some index? this particular index you need to select in kibana

Comment: The problem is that I don't see any App indexes in Kibana. While elasticsearch_im_app_XXXXXXXX job has output as shown in the question above.